# Thread in Android game - how to implement?

Tags: android, multithreading

I am implementing checkers as a game for Android. I am able to move with my pieces and with "computer" pieces. I am going to add AI for computer somehow, but now I am stuck with Threading. This is my game activity for checkers (Game.java):

```
private SachovniceView sachovniceView;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    chessboardView = new chessboardView(this);
    setContentView(chessboardView);
    chessboardView.requestFocus();

}
```

in chessboardView I draw in Canvas chessboard and I have here method for drawing mine and my opponent's game pieces and method (both in @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) method) for moving my pieces. I am storing position of gamepieces in [][] field, when I move with my stone, I invalidate() chesssboard for redrawing. And Here is the thing - how to implement Threads in my game? I am absolutely lost. I think I have to give away method for moving stones and make it alone as a class with name human_turn, then I have to make the same with computer (like computer_turn) and somehow implement Thread logic. My turn, opponent thread is stopped, I finish my move, opponent thread is going to alive, my thread is stopping and so on. I have spent whole day on the internet, but I didn't get the Thread thing in my head :-( Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Hmyzak

Comment: Isn't Checkers turn-based? If yes you would not need threads at all. When the player finished, make the field un-touchable, let the AI think the move, make the move, restore the field for inputs and go on, right? If you want threads (if your AI is really really CPU intensive), then I would go for a AsyncTask for the CPU AI (instantiate everytime the CPU needs to make a move). Your players input doesn't need any threading.

Comment: Wow, you really brighten up my day! You are right, no need for thread :-) thanks a lot and have a nice day

Comment: you would still need a thread if it takes longer than say a 1/4 second to compute the move, you don't want to lock up the UI thread.  But threading is easy in android you can use an `AsyncTask` or `Thread` + `Runnable`